# How Is Mixed Norm ($ {L}_{1, 2 }$) Better than $ {L}_{1} $ Norm for Sparse Representation?

Tags: matrix, compressive-sensing, optimization, source-separation, sparsity

Using $ {l}_{1} $-norm regularization for the purpose of achieving sparsity of the solution has been successfully applied a lot. But many times, I found the paper using mixed-norm instead of $l_1$-norm.

Considering the mixed norm $ {L}_{p,q}$ norm defined as:

$$ {\left\| a \right\|}_{p,q} = \left( \sum_{i} \left( \sum_{j} {\left| {a}_{i,j} \right|}^{p} \right)^{ 
\frac{q}{p} } \right)^{ \frac{1}{q} } $$

How is mixed-norm better than $l1$-norm for sparse representation? Most of what I have seen is $l_{1,2}$.

Reference, for example,

- [Sparse Nonnegative Matrix Factorization for Clustering](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~hpark/papers/GT-CSE-08-01.pdf) eq.12
- [Compressive Sensing of Jointly Sparse Signals as a Method for
  Dimensionality reduction of Mass Spectrometry Data](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8053334) eq.7
- [L1/2 Sparsity Constrained Nonnegative Matrix Factorization for Hyperspectral Unmixing](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5692602)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mixed norm allows you to impose some simple structure in the solution matrix. Using your example with $p=q=1$ then this means the solution could have arbitrary elements set to non-zero coefficients. This would not impose any structure in the solution. In this case the $L_{11} $ norm just sums the absolute value of all the matrix elements - similar to the Frobenius norm.

As an example, consider that $L_{11}$ norm of the following matrices are the same:

$\begin{bmatrix} 0&2 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \quad \begin{bmatrix} 0&0 \\ 2 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \quad \begin{bmatrix} 2&0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \quad \begin{bmatrix} 0&0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$.

So there is no preference as to which element is set to non-zero

Instead, if $p=2$ and $q=1$, then the objective function is minimizing the $l_2$ norm of the columns and then the $l_1$ norm over the that. This means you're looking for an $a$ matrix with a sparse number of column vectors and where each column vector has a small $l_2$ norm. Of course this assumes you are using the $l_1$ norm as a proxy for sparsity.

Consider the $L_{2,1}$ and $L_{1,2}$ norms of following matrices:

$\begin{bmatrix} 2&0 \\ 2 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \quad L_{2,1} = \sqrt{8} \approx 2.8, \quad L_{1,2} = 4
$

and

$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0\\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}, \quad L_{2,1}= 4, \quad L_{1,2} = \sqrt{8}
$

So minimizing the $L_{2,1}$ norm tends to prefer the structure of the first matrix over the second one, while minimizing the $L_{1,2}$ norm tends to prefer the structure second matrix over the first.

Thus the mixed norm allows you impose a soft constraint on the structure of the sparse solution that you're looking for. It's relatively easy to see that be you could also set it up to look for a sparse set of row vectors, each with a small $l_2$ norm. Deciding which to use is really dependent on how you set up your equations.

Comment: May you explain why “with $p = q = 1$ , this means the solution could have arbitrary elements set to non-zero coefficients”? May be I miss some points but not $L_{1}$ forces the coefficient to be zero as many as possible?

Comment: $L_1$ is normally used as a substitute for $L_0$, in order to make the problem convex - so I'm assuming you are looking for a sparse solution - as per the title of your question. Using $L_{11}$  the matrix $[ 0, 2, 0 ,0]$ and $[0, 0, 0, 2]$ have the same have the same norm.

Comment: I updated my answer to try to be more explicit. It is difficult to typeset matrices in the comments.

Comment: Thanks so much for updating the answer with matrices. One thing is may you check the paragraph before the last paragraph pls? $L2,1$ are written twice and I wonder may be one of them should be $L1,2$ norm?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I made the correction. If the post does answer your question then I'd appreciate the upvote.

Comment: Sorry for taking time to understand this. May I ask some more that in your example, do I understand correctly that $L_{1,2}$ prefers data to be in different row but $L_{2,1}$ prefers data to be in different column? And can I minimizing $L_{p,q}$ norm in the same way as $L1$ norm? Such as if $log(\epsilon + \vert\vert X \vert\vert_{1})$ is convergent, $log(\epsilon + \vert\vert X \vert\vert_{1,2})$ is also convergent?

Comment: Not quite - because the order you are taking the $l_1$ and $l_2$ norm changes. Note that in my example the second matrix has a $L_{1,2} =\sqrt{8}$, but the elements are not in a single row. You'd have to change the order of the summation or transpose the matrix to make it the same. You should be able to use similar techniques, but they may require modifications.